# Flutter icon how to fill all the width and height available in the tab

Tags: flutter, card

i've a card like this.
[Actual card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15FMu.jpg)

but i want a card like this
[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKTaO.jpg)

My code is:

```
return Card(
      semanticContainer: true,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 5.0, 20.0, 5.0),
      elevation: 5.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Example text'),
                Text("20-06-2021 - 13:00",
                    style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                Text("Example text"),
                Text("Example text"),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flag(
                  'FR',
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  replacement: Text('Error'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Now, i have fixed height and width, i'm not able to obtain what i want because each attempt enlarge the card in height.
(I  want to keep the same height as the card above).
The icons comes from the package flags ([Flags package](https://pub.dev/packages/flag))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wrapping a `Container` in a `Card`. Try to Wrap a `Row` with `Expanded` in the `Card`. (I just changed the Container into padding)

```dart
        Card(
            semanticContainer: true,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 5.0, 20.0, 5.0),
            elevation: 5.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Example text'),
                        Text("20-06-2021 - 13:00",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                        Text("Example text"),
                        Text("Example text"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image: above is your example. Below is the use of row with expanded]

Answer (score 0):

try this
to let it fit the width and the height:

```
Flag('AD', height: double.infinity, width: double.infinity, fit: BoxFit.fill)
```

or maybe this:

```
Flag('AD', height: null, width: null, fit: BoxFit.fill)
```

I recommend to make this flag Expandable widget inside the row

Answer (score 0):

wrapped your **Flag** inside **SizedBox** if you know what fixed size it is like this.

```
SizedBox(
  height: 65,
  width: 140,
  child: Flag(
    'FR',
    replacement: Text('Error'),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
)
```

More about SizedBox [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)